# Add Webparts through SharePoint hosted app

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I am trying to add a webpart trough and app. I have provisioned some files in different extensions sucessfully.

The last step for my app is to add a content editor web part on the hostweb welcome page, now it says undefined. Heres my code:

```
"use strict";
//Provision Web Part on Host Web
var hostweb;
var hosturl;

function getRelativeUrlFromAbsolute(absoluteUrl) {
absoluteUrl = absoluteUrl.replace('https://', '');
var parts = absoluteUrl.split('/');
var relativeUrl = '/';
for (var i = 1; i < parts.length; i++) {

    relativeUrl += parts[i] + '/';
}
return relativeUrl;
}

function getQueryStringParameter(param) {
var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
    var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
    if (singleParam[0] == param) {
        return singleParam[1];
    }
 }
}

function addWebPart() {

var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
var currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var hostcontext = new SP.AppContextSite(currentcontext, hostUrl);
var hostweb = hostcontext.get_web();

//add a content editor web part to the default.aspx page
                                                                //Default.aspx
var pageToAddWP = hostweb.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(hostUrl +    "SitePages/DevHome.aspx");

//get out webpartmanager object for imports
var limitedWebPartManager = pageToAddWP.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);

var webPartXml = '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>' +
    '<WebPart xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"' + 
    ' xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"' + 
    ' xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2\">' + 
    '<Title>My Web Part</Title><FrameType>Default</FrameType>' + 
    '<Description>Use for formatted text, tables, and images.</Description>' + 
    '<IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded><ZoneID></ZoneID><PartOrder>0</PartOrder>' + 
    '<FrameState>Normal</FrameState><Height /><Width /><AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>' + 
    '<AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange><AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>' + 
    '<AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect><AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>' + 
    '<AllowHide>true</AllowHide><IsVisible>true</IsVisible><DetailLink /><HelpLink />' + 
    '<HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode><Dir>Default</Dir><PartImageSmall />' + 
    '<MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>' + 
    '<PartImageLarge>/_layouts/images/mscontl.gif</PartImageLarge><IsIncludedFilter />' + 
    '<Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, ' + 
    'PublicKeyToken=94de0004b6e3fcc5</Assembly>' + 
    '<TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart</TypeName>' + 
    '<ContentLink xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor\" />' + 
    '<Content xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor\">' + 
    '<![CDATA[This is a first paragraph!<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>And this is a second paragraph.]]></Content>' + 
    '<PartStorage xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor\" /></WebPart>';


var webPartDefinition = limitedWebPartManager.importWebPart(webPartXml);
var webpart = webPartDefinition.get_webPart();

limitedWebPartManager.addWebPart(webpart, "Left", 1);

currentcontext.load(webpart);
currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(onAddWPSuccess, onAddWPFailed);
}
function onAddWPSuccess() {

 $('#message').append('<br /><div>WebPart succesfully added!</div>');
}
  function onAddWPFailed(sender, args){

$('#message').append('<br />Failed to provision webpart into host web. Error:' +   sender.statusCode);
 }
```

Comment: What says undefined?

Comment: It says: Value does not fall within the expected range.

Comment: I have the same issue :(

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the relative URL:

```
var pageToAddWP = hostweb.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(getRelativeUrlFromAbsolute(hostUrl) + "SitePages/DevHome.aspx");
```

Also, change the assembly version to 16 in your webPartXml code.

```
<Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
```

Comment: I get this error: Value does not fall within the expected range. My code works when i not use it in a app

Comment: I fixed it, the right way was "/sites/mysitecollection/SitePages/home.aspx"